# GridPane within a ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx

I wrapped a `GridPane` in a `ScrollPane` to be able to scroll it when new rows are added to the Grid.

```
<BorderPane fx:id="SubmitStageBorderPane" 
stylesheets="@../SubmitStageStyles.css" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112-ea" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SubmitStage">
   <center>
  <AnchorPane fx:id="SubmitStageAnchorPane">
     <children>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="GridscPane" hbarPolicy="NEVER" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS">
           <content>
              <GridPane fx:id="submitLayout" maxHeight="1080.0" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" stylesheets="@../SubmitStageStyles.css">
                <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="course1" promptText="Course name" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <opaqueInsets>
                          <Insets />
                       </opaqueInsets>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="course2" promptText="Cource name" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="course3" promptText="Course name" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="course4" promptText="Course name" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Grade:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Grade:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Grade:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Grade:" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <TextField fx:id="grade1" promptText="Enter the grade" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="grade2" promptText="Enter the grade" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="grade3" promptText="Enter the grade" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="grade4" promptText="Enter the grade" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Credits:" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Credits:" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Credits:" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </Label>
                    <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Credits:" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="15.0" top="10.0" />
                       </padding>
                       <font>
                          <Font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Label>
                    <TextField fx:id="credit1" promptText="Course credit" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="credit2" promptText="Course credit" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="credit3" promptText="Course credit" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                    <TextField fx:id="credit4" promptText="Course credit" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                       <GridPane.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </GridPane.margin>
                    </TextField>
                 </children>
                 <opaqueInsets>
                    <Insets />
                   </opaqueInsets>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                 </padding>
              </GridPane>
           </content>
        </ScrollPane>
        <Button fx:id="AddAnotherCourseButton" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#AddAnotherCourseClicked" text="ADD ANOTHER COURSE">
           <font>
              <Font name="Book Antiqua Bold" size="15.0" />
           </font>
        </Button>
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</center>
<top>
  <MenuBar fx:id="SubmitStageMenuBar" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load" />
              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="About">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
</top>
</BorderPane>
```

I have a button that whenever it's clicked, a row with elements is added to the `GridPane`.

```
public void AddAnotherCourseClicked(){

    int rowCount = returnMaxRow();

    TextField courseName = new TextField();
    courseName.setPromptText("Course name");
    submitLayout.setMargin(courseName, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

    Label gradeLabel = new Label("Grade:");
    gradeLabel.setFont(Font.font("Eras Demi ITC", 21));
    submitLayout.setMargin(gradeLabel, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    gradeLabel.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 15, 10));

    TextField gradeReceived = new TextField();
    gradeReceived.setPromptText("Enter the grade");
    submitLayout.setMargin(gradeReceived, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

    Label creditsLabel = new Label("Credits:");
    creditsLabel.setFont(Font.font("Eras Demi ITC", 21));
    submitLayout.setMargin(gradeLabel, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    creditsLabel.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 15, 10));

    TextField courseCredit = new TextField();
    courseCredit.setPromptText("Course credit");
    submitLayout.setMargin(courseCredit, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

    submitLayout.addRow(rowCount+1, courseName, gradeLabel, gradeReceived, creditsLabel, courseCredit);
}

private int returnMaxRow(){
    int rowNum, lastRow = 0;
    for(Node element : submitLayout.getChildren()){
        rowNum = submitLayout.getRowIndex(element);
        lastRow = (rowNum > lastRow ? rowNum : lastRow);
    }
    return lastRow;
}
```

Thus far, the `ScrollBar` is added however, when i press the button, the rows are simply clustered together, and the `ScrollBar` doesn't extend, its height remains the same.

Comment: Don't set the `maxHeight` and `prefHeight` on the `GridPane.`

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on the same problem, and I don't know what I did, but somehow it got fixed and my FXML file became like this:

```
<ScrollPane layoutX="68.0" layoutY="426.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="763.0">
    <content>
      <GridPane fx:id="gp_result" alignment="CENTER" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="763.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="376.4000244140625" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="85.19996643066406" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="678.8000335693359" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="678.8000335693359" />
        </columnConstraints>
      </GridPane>
    </content>
  </ScrollPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue.. looked everywhere... finally there was one way around..

Just don't add the grid pane using the scene builder ...just create the scroll pane using the scene builder and then add the grid pane dynamically using the code and do like below

```
// create new constraints for columns and set their percentage
ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
columnConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100.00);

// create new constraints for row and set their percentage
RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
rowConstraints.setVgrow(Priority.NEVER);

columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100.0);

// don't set preferred size or anything on gridpane
GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();  
gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);
gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);

// suppose your scroll pane id is scrollPane
scrollPane.setContent(gridPane);
```

Finally in scene builder remember to tick FitHeight and FitWidth for scrollpane so that grid pane will stretch to fit the scroll pane size when the grid is added on the go